# In Selenium WebDriver, how do I find an element with a DOM ID and no className?

Tags: java, selenium, element

The element I am trying to manipulate is a drop down autocomplete text box.  However rather than be a normal text box its this:

```
<input class="rad-input acInput float_left edScheduleList 
ui-autocomplete-input" style="width: 234px; font-size: 12px; 
font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Times New Roman; padding-left: 4px; 
line-height: 12px;" placeholder="Select Schedule..." data-bind="click: _editorOverlay.Overlay.CustomRecVM.scheduleData.ac.dropdownArrowClick,
    enable: _editorOverlay.Overlay.CustomRecVM.scheduleEnabled,
    jqAuto: { autoFocus: true }, 
    jqAutoSource: editorOverlay.Overlay.CustomRecVM.scheduleData.list, 
    jqAutoQuery: editorOverlay.Overlay.CustomRecVM.scheduleData.GetList,
    jqAutoValue: _editorOverlay.Overlay.CustomRecVM.scheduleData.selectedID, 
    jqAutoSourceLabel: 'Text', 
    jqAutoSourceInputValue: 'Text', 
    jqAutoSourceValue: 'Value',
     jqChange: _editorOverlay.Overlay.CustomRecVM.ScheduleIndexChanged"    id="domId08015369399681067" autocomplete="off">
```

I can't find it by id, cssSelector, xpath, className, name, or class.  I have tried partial or containing text and am still getting no where.  I am using Java for this.

Comment: It would help to see what you have tried but didn't work.

Comment: Is this inside a unique div that you can use to find it?  css selector something like div#uniqueId > input

Comment: this is the selector I get:  #domId0929060823760302 and this is the xpath i get: //*[@id="domId0929060823760302"] when I inspect using the browser.  I have tried using id domId08015369399681067 as well.

Comment: Is it inside an iframe?

Comment: Not inside an iFrame that would make it easy.  It's inside a draggable overlay ui object.  If the user clicks on something it will open up this ui overlay and give them other options.  Right now I can direct the driver to the overlay and insure its there, but this specific element is giving me the most trouble I have ever had.

Comment: @JoeC okay, but what error do you get when you try locating it?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"domId08015369399681067"}.  No matter what I use I continually get the same exception, just updated for the method I am trying to use, id, css, xpath, name, ect.

Comment: Is `id` static or dynamic? If static, then `//input[@id='domId08015369399681067']` is correct xpath. If it cannot find it, I would wait for it instead: `WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible(By.id("domId08015369399681067")));`. If that still doesn't work, dump the page contents right at exception, and see what selenium actually sees. Posting that page content here may help.

Comment: Neither of those worked unfortunately.  I wonder if this has anything to do with the object interacting with JQuery.  I've not researched how to dump the page content upon exception.  Are you talking about grabbing the page source in total or just the element in question?

Comment: @JoeC, you mentioned that you can direct the driver to the overlay to ensure that it is there.  Can you get the driver to find other elements in the overlay?  If you can ensure that it's there, are there other inputs in that control, or can you use my earlier suggestion to use a locator for the overlay element and its input child?

Comment: I can interact with all other elements and found a round about way using actions and sending down arrow and enter keys yesterday.  It worked but its not production level solution like I am looking for.  However I did find a more permanent solution I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I could just use cssSelector for the class name.  I am still relatively new to Selenium and did not know I could combine class names and cssSelector methods.  The above element can be manipulated with the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("input[class='rad-input acInput float_left edScheduleList ui-autocomplete-input']"));
```

Thanks for the help guys, the class name was really throwing me off.  I thought because the selector was coming back as a dom I had to treat it differently.